# SharePoint Online List limitations

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, custom-list, excel-services, odata

Is it just me or is it really strange that SSRS 2012 still does not support Claims based authentication or OData connections? Anybody know of plans? Reasons for such a hole in the strategy?

Part of a bigger issue with a series of SPO misses and limitations relating to SharePoint Online Lists.

- SPD 2013 Drops Design view making Data View Web Parts nearly impossible
- SPO Excel Web Access can't connect and refresh SPO List data
- SSRS Integrated not supported on SPO.
- SSRS On-Prem has no Claims Based auth option or OData connector
- SSRS has SP list connector, but can't connect to SPO Lists Natively
- SPO 5000 row limit now stops views with any aggregator controls from working

Is there any hope that any of this will sort itself out?

We heard all the hype about FoSL in March, so where is it? Will it have a WYSIWYG View designer? Will it allow those views outside of the App context?

We are trying not to invest in 3rd party form and connector products in hopes that MS at least builds connectivity and functionality for SPO Lists.   IMO, The SP list is the heart of SharePoint, so why it being restricted in so many ways online?

Answer (score 1):

All of the above is true. FoSL is cancelled, but there are alternatives. Here is a good article listing some of them: http://en.share-gate.com/blog/5-alternatives-to-infopath-for-sharepoint-forms

I myself am using OData as an external data connection in Excel, and it refreshes with no problem, only the filters are tricky. Also since InfoPath is back from the dead, I have been able to use it for about 90% of the things I need to do, most of which is on your list.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen, you may want to consider looking at PowerBI.

1. You would have to look at the Power BI Gateway $10/mo per user for any On-Prem reporting needs. Consumers of the report wouldn't count.  The gateway just accesses your on prem to get data.
2. Power BI does support oAuth

I know this doesn't cover your need for SSRS.  However, looking ahead at SSRS 2014/2016 when PowerBI is being integrated more into SSRS.

Answer (score -1):

Use the following link to get all the list libraries limitations
Software boundaries and limits for SharePoint 2013 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx#ListLibrary

Comment: Your answer for the question is not applicable.. also make sure you provide brief summary and not just link and one liner in your answer..

Comment: Dear Ankit the above link is from the Microsoft Team. That is providing the correct answer so I have given that link